# match two elements in an array with a single for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
var fl = myitems(); //grabs all items (an array)
var f1 = f2 = new String();


function myfunc(){
    //find two items in an array and load vars
    for(i=0; i<fl.length-1; i++){
        if(fl[i] == "match1"){
            f1 = fl[i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<fl.length-1; i++){
        if(fl[i] == "match2"){
            f2 = fl[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to avoid the extra for(), if possible.  I try else if, but many times the first match element is caught after the 2nd element has already been surpassed in the for loop.

I'm sure there is an easy way out of this (`else if`, and `else` don't seem to do the trick).

Can anyone tell me what common practice is here?

Comment: You should use the `===` or `==` comparison operator instead of the `=` which is _assignment_!

Comment: Common practice is to use `''` not `new String`, and not to use confusing variables like `fl` and `f1`, and to declare variables with `var` in `for` loops, and to use comparison operators not assignments in `if` statments. Many things went wrong....

Comment: You can also use localeCompare() to compare string. and i suggest you rather than avoid two for loop and add two condition in only one for loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "match two elements"? If you are just going to compare them to a string, why not just setting f1 to "match1" instead of looping?

Comment: @elclanrs, I don't need to declare the vars in the for because they are global scope.

Comment: His point was that you should ADD 'var', just to avoid cluttering the global object.

Comment: I disagree - I need that var to be updated in global scope periodically.  var would change the scope to being local to my function, and it's defined outside of the scope of my function.  I'll update that in my question.

Comment: He meant the counter. "for(var i...)". You are creating a property called i on the global object while running your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both tests in the same loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < fl.length - 1; i++) {
    if (fl[i] == "match1") {
        f1 = fl[i];
    } else if (fl[i] == "match2") {
        f2 = fl[i];
    }
}
```

Note that the comparison operator is `==`, not `=`.

Comment: Apologies for the poor syntax.  I modified my code and what happens is that f2's match string has already passed once 'i' is incremented to that point.

Comment: You are checking for both matches EVERY iteration of the loop.

Comment: You'll probably need to use equals("match1") and equals("match2") to compare strings, if you're checking values; == will check object identity.

Comment: @JoseTepedino `==` works fine with strings in Javascript. You're thinking of some other language.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the "Javascript" tag! This syntax is very similar to C# (and Java).
<br/>
One question: the loop above will get the last matches, if there is more than one occurrence of the search strings; is this the desired result?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. Either way, `f1` will be set to `"match1"` and `f2` will be set to `"match2"`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this does not answer the original question, but it looks like you are trying to find out whether the arrays contain 'match1' and 'match2', you can do that with [**Array.prototype.indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var items = myitems();
if(items.indexOf('match1') !== -1) {
    // Do whatever you need to do if the array contains 'match1'
}
```

Comment: Good luck with your program :)

Comment: If you have `m` strings to search for, this will be `(n*m)`. Combining them into one loop as in my answer is `O(n+m)`.